# Python print turtle.pos()

Tags: python, vector, printing

I'm trying to write a program that draws shapes based on user input. I want it to print where each corner of the shape is based on using the `turtle.pos()` function, however I'm trying to get the printed output as so:

```
"The first corner is at: x, y, with a heading of: d."
```

Currently the print I'm using is

```
print("The first corner is at:", turtle.position(), "with a heading of:" turtle.heading() + ".")
```

And this outputs as:

```
"The first corner is at: (x, y,), with a heading of: d."
```

So printing the `turtle.pos()` returns the coords as a tuple, and prints as `(X, y)`. When I try to format as int, it gives me an error about needing str, not vec2d.  How would I format that output? Or am I completely going about that the wrong way?

Comment: Python, sorry this is my first time using this site and I thought I was in a specifically python forum.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out- somehow I forgot about

```
turtle.xcor()/turtle.ycor()
```

And was able to print those as integers instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
print("The first corner is at:", turtle.position()[0], "with a heading of:" 
    turtle.heading() + ".")
```

Comment: Is it seriously that simple?! I feel really dumb now.

Comment: Yep. Tuples can be used like arrays.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm going for- it only prints the x coord though, and has a crazy long decimal. How do i go about making it print both coords and dropping all deicmals?

Comment: Actually, after looking at it again,  I'm not sure what that's doing- the single number it's printing appears to be a subtraction/addition of the x and y values